# RichTextBox doesn't use the RTF font name

Tags: wpf, rtf

I have a WPF `RichTextBox`

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="txtMain" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

and I'm assigning it some RTF formatted text via `DataFormats.Rtf`

```
string rtf = "\\li90{\\cf0 Marc Says:}\\par\\li180{{\\fonttbl {\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Consolas;}}\\cf2\\fs18 Test font name}\\par"

FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtf));
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd);
textRange.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
txtMain.Document = fd;
```

However, instead of using the RTF font name **Consolas**, the `RichTextBox` is using the default assigned **Segoe UI** font name.

Ideas?

Comment: Turns out I just had to add \deff0 after my \rtf1\ansi.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtf));
```

to

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtf));
```

Also make sure your `RTF` is correct.

Comment: I know my RTF is correct because it works with the WinForms RichTextBox. I've tried using UTF8 without success.

Comment: The RTF generated by Winforms RTB is different in WPF. It should always start with `{\\rtf1`